# How to make soundcloud embedding work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, embed, soundcloud

Soundcloud embedding works in every browser except internet explorer.

Steps to reproduce:

-Observe that a page that embedded soundcloud works in most browsers but freezes in internet explorer (makes internet explorer unresponsive)

-Also observe that if you go to the url of the embed, it will work on most browsers but cause internet explorer to crash.

Version: 11.0.9600.17105

Update Versions: 11.0.7 (KB2964358)

Using Windows 8.1 64-bit